# Why did Joey Gazelle choose this exit strategy at the end of Running Scared?

Tags: ending, running-scared

I just don't understand why Paul Walker's character faked his death at the end of *Running Scared*.

I did some research online and there's an answer that says that he's a rat and was put in WITSEC?

He's obviously not a rat because he said in the movie:

> I was undercover for 12 years and my wife doesn't even know about it.

So I guess the term "undercover" doesn't apply for rats right?

Answer (score 3):

Joey Gazelle faked his own death to protect himself and his family for the reminder of their [lives](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_Scared_(2006_film)).

> A funeral is held for Joey with Teresa, Nicky, and Oleg in attendance,
>   and Oleg has been adopted into the family. They drive out to a small
>   farm house, where Joey's car is parked in the driveway. Teresa sits on
>   the car's bumper when Joey emerges from under the car, alive and well,
>   **having faked his own death for his protection as an undercover
>   officer.**

**The definition of an undercover officer is as as** [follows](http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1O999-undercover.html):

> an individual involved in or involving secret work within a community
>   or organization, esp. for the purposes of police investigation or
>   espionage: an undercover police operation.

Answer (score 0):

He was FBI, undercover.  He was put into WITSEC after the events of the movie for the protection of his cover/identity/whatever.  That's what I've gathered about it.